# Inline helpers and page output - how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have an HtmlHelper function that returns a `MvcHtmlString` and which I'd like to call in an inline helper like this:

```
@helper JsCss()
{
    Html.Script("jquery/jquery-1.6.2", cdn: true)
}
```

I call the inline helper from my page:

```
<head>
@JsCss()
</head>
```

...trouble is: nothing shows up on the page!  it seems I have to do this:

```
@helper JsCss()
{
    <text>
    @Html.Script("jquery/jquery-1.6.2", cdn: true)
    </text>
}
```

so I guess the thing is I have to "print" the return value of my `Html.Script` call to the page... how else could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A helper is a code block, you need to prefix the `Html.Script` with `@` so Razor knows you want to output the return value (you don't need the `<text></text>`):

```
@helper JsCss()
{
    @Html.Script("jquery/jquery-1.6.2", cdn: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm being a dope.  2 months of not touching this stuff and I've already forgotten!  thanks