# How do I make a method in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Before I start, I know this NOT considered good practice, but was wondering how (if at all) it would be possible to define a method inside my view.

Im using C# in ASP.Net MVC

The following does not seem to work:

```
decimal DoCalculation(IEnumerable<MyItems> items){
    ...
}
```

**N.B. I AM NOT USING THE RAZOR VIEW ENGINE**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define a method in Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159877/how-do-i-define-a-method-in-razor)

Comment: You should really put this code inside your model. This is swimming against the MVC current.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the Razor view engine you could declare [`inline functions`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax.aspx):

```
@functions {
    public string DoCalculation(IEnumerable<MyItems> items) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

or also you could use [`inline helpers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449728/inline-helpers-and-page-output-how):

```
@helper DoCalculationAndOutputResult(IEnumerable<MyItems> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <div>@item.SomeValue</div>
    }
}
```

And if you are using the WebForms view engine:

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    public string DoCalculation(IEnumerable<MyItems> items) {
        ...    
    }
</script>
```

Obviously writing C# code in views is as bad as not writing any code at all. Worth mentioning for other people reading this so that they do not do the same mistake as you.

Comment: But this doesn't return anything.

Comment: Isn't the syntax for this `@helper`?

Comment: @Jon, in Razor you have `@functions` and `@helper`, which are 2 completely different things.

Comment: @Frederiek, no it doesn't. That's a function declaration. Did you call it somewhere in your Razor view so that it returns something?